# MS Excel Formula: Sort Data by Length AND Alphabetically (Descending Order)

Tags: excel, sorting, formula

I would like to know with the use of a MS EXCEL FORMULA (v. 2010), that will allow me to sort a list of Orginal Non-Alphabetical Text in Column (Cell B2:B16) using multiple conditions to sort text by "Length" (Cell A2:A16) in Descending Order and then by text "Alphabetically" in Descending Order.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use the Sort provided in excel? First by column A in Descending, then column B descending

Comment: I'm familiar with the built-in MS Excel sort function, unfortunately, due to the assigned project, it requires that if at all possible to use a MS Excel formula, excluding both VBA/Macro and Microsoft Sort function.

Comment: So this is homework?

Comment: Yes, but what was once homework (project assignment), has turned in to an all-out obsession, to see if it can be done... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change the formula in Column A to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT({100,20,1}*(CODE(MID(B2,{1,2,3},1))))*LEN(B2)
```

This gives a number based on the ASCII codes of the first 3 letters in the name and multiplies that with the number of characters.  The first {100,20,1} weights the first letter above the second above the third.  Other wise there are ties.

Then in C2 put:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$16,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$16,ROW(1:1)),$A$2:$A$16,0))
```

This puts in order the numbers in Column A and returns the appropriate name associated with it.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: WOW and WOW... Thank you so very much, the provided formula worked flawlessly... I'm very thankful for your help.. thank you.

Comment: @Miaka3 I overthought the second formula.  See the edit, you may need to refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you again, I made the recommended edit and update and the revised edition works very well in achieving the Sort Text in Descending Order by Length and Alphabetically... thank you